# C++ Updating data and rendering

Tags: c++, multithreading, sleep

I'm making a program that can update the states of objects whilst rendering.

So my first approach was the obvious draw and update in the main while loop, but this problem limited the update state part to the speed of rendering (the computer speed) so this wasn't a good approach.

So I tried to think about the problem and came up with a solution that making a detached thread whose purpose is to update the game. Here is my code of this:

```cpp
//DEFAULT
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

//SFML
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

void sleep_fnc(bool*);
void update_game(bool*/*, Some objects...*/);

#define cycles_per_milisecond 1000/30

int main() {
    bool flag = true;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(680, 480), "I work!");

    std::thread (sleep_fnc, &flag).detach();
    std::thread(update_game, &flag/*, Some objects...*/).detach();

    if (window.isOpen()) {

        window.clear();

        //DRAW STUFF HERE

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

void sleep_fnc(bool *flag_ptr) {
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(cycles_per_milisecond));
        *flag_ptr = true;
    }
}

void update_game(bool *flag_ptr/*, Some objects...*/) {
    while (true) {
        if (*flag_ptr) {
            //Do update stuff
            *flag_ptr = false;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
}
```

After I fiddled around with this code someone else realized that this wasn't such a good solution (thanks to you whomever pointed it out). The reason for this is if one object is being modified by the update loop WHILE the render loop is in its cycle something undefined would probably be the outcome, so I went back and started thinking again.

After thinking I came up with a solution that every class could inherit some universal class that had a boolean whether the object was being used by the draw loop or update loop, if it was in use, one of the loops would wait until the boolean flag indicated that it was ready for use again. It would probably be best if the update loop wasn't the one to wait.

Then it finally hit me that drawing the objects would be useless if they hadn't been updated. I believe that using a timer to test execution time and using that is unreliable, and there must be some other way than limiting the frame rate.

Would this prove that a frame rate higher than the update-rate is useless and is there some other approach that doesn't involve testing the execution time of last cycle and using that?

Comment: Use C++11 [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) & [threading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) facilities (in particular `std::mutex` & `std::condition_variable` ....). Read some [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). On POSIX systems you might also have a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to yourself and have it polled in the GUI main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know mutex and condition variables were a thing!

Comment: In essence you "stumbled" upon the concept of a mutes with your "some kind of boolean per object that indicates whether it is being used in update or render" :)